# Regex mask replacement pattern for Phonenumber

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am new to regex 
I have phone number regex pattern  as (?\d{3})?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}

I am trying to mask phone number to display only last 4 digits.

I am using a function Regex.Replace("(123) 556-7890 ", "(?\d{3})?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}", "#")

Would some one help me what would be the replace pattern.

I need out put like for . Input can be XML or JSON

**Input**
PhoneNumber> (123) 556-7890  PhoneNumber>

**Output**
PhoneNumber>(XXX) XXX-7890 PhoneNumber>

**Input**
PhoneNumber> 123 556 7890 PhoneNumber>

**Output**
PhoneNumber>XXX XXX 7890 PhoneNumber>

**Input**
PhoneNumber> (123) 556- 7890 PhoneNumber>

**Output**
PhoneNumber>(XXX) XXX- 7890 PhoneNumber>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you simply save the latest 4 digits with `\d{4}$` and then mock-up the previous codes? :)

Comment: var replaceString = Regex.Replace("<PhoneNumber>(754) 765-8769</PhoneNumber>", "\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}", "###-##-\d{4}$");      result is coming as <PhoneNumber>###-##-\d{4}$</PhoneNumber>

Comment: regexp: `([\(?(\d{0,3})\)?\s]+[-\s])(?=\d{4})`
replace: `XXX-XXX-`

Comment: Better `([\(?(\d{0,3})\)?\s]+[-\s]+)`

Answer (score 11):

You can use a regex to match any digit that is not within the last 4 digits at the end of the string, and replace with an `X`:

```
\d(?!\d{0,3}$)
```

*Explantion*:

- `\d` - match a digit and...
- `(?!\d{0,3}$)` - fail the match if there is 0 to 3 digits right at the end of the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJ2vY5/2) and this [C# demo](http://ideone.com/pC9Adj):

```
var data = new string[] {"(123) 556-7890", "123 556 7890", "(123) 556- 7890"};
foreach (var s in data) {
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"\d(?!\d{0,3}$)", "X"));
```

Results:

```
(XXX) XXX-7890
XXX XXX 7890
(XXX) XXX- 7890
```

**UPDATE showing how to use YOUR regex combined with mine**

You just need to use your regex to match the phone numbers in the required format, and use mine to mask the digits inside a match evaluator:

```
var data = "I have this (123) 556-7890 phone number, followed with 123 556 7890, and (123) 556- 7890.";
var res = Regex.Replace(data, @"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}", 
                x => Regex.Replace(x.Value, @"\d(?!\d{0,3}$)", "X"));
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/1hiJ4a)

**NOTE** that `@"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}\b"` or `@"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}(?!\d)"` might be better patterns to extract phone numbers as the final 4 digits cannot be followed by a word/non-digit character.

Comment: it's not working if the  input is "<PhoneNumber>(123) 556-7890</PhoneNumber>" for this input expected out put is <PhoneNumber>(XXX) XXX-8769</PhoneNumber>

Comment: Do not replace XML directly. Parse it with appropriate tools and then replace plain text only. But surely you can replace `$` with `<` or even `</PhoneNumber>`

Comment: @Tim007 If the input contains multiple phone numbers, all OP needs is to use a phone extraction regex and replace the digits with this regex.

Comment: @user3681378: I will repeat: parse JSON/XML with appropriate tools, and replace only the required fields. Otherwise, you risk matching what you do not need and failing to match what you need.

Comment: can you please help me with how to make regular expression for XX543252XX ?

Answer (score 5):

If it's always the same number of digits, do you need to do a replace? Surely just taking the last four digits and putting `(XXX) XXX-` in front of it would achieve the same result?

```
string masked = "(XXX) XXX-" + input.Substring(input.Length - 4);
```

Obviously you should still use your original regex to make sure it's a valid phone number first.

Comment: no flynn i can't do that because it is a common function which should work for SSN etc based on patterns

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
(\d)([() -]*)(\d)([() -]*)(\d)([() -]*)(\d)([() -]*)(\d)([() -]*)(\d)([() -]*)(\d+)
```

Substitution

```
x\2x\4x\6x\8x\10x\12\13
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJ3eF4/4)

Input

```
Input
PhoneNumber> (123) 556-7890 PhoneNumber>

Output PhoneNumber>(XXX) XXX-7890 PhoneNumber>

Input
PhoneNumber> 123 556 7890 PhoneNumber>

Output PhoneNumber>XXX XXX 7890 PhoneNumber>

Input
PhoneNumber> (123) 556- 7890 PhoneNumber>

Output PhoneNumber>(XXX) XXX- 7890 PhoneNumber>
```

Output

```
Input
PhoneNumber> (xxx) xxx-7890 PhoneNumber>

Output PhoneNumber>(XXX) XXX-7890 PhoneNumber>

Input
PhoneNumber> xxx xxx 7890 PhoneNumber>

Output PhoneNumber>XXX XXX 7890 PhoneNumber>

Input
PhoneNumber> (xxx) xxx- 7890 PhoneNumber>

Output PhoneNumber>(XXX) XXX- 7890 PhoneNumber>
```

Comment: Regex.Replace("<PhoneNumber> (123) 556-7890 </PhoneNumber>", @"(\d)([() -]*)(\d)([() -]*)(\d)([() -]*)(\d)([() -]*)(\d)([() -]*)(\d)([() -]*)(\d+)", "x\\2x\\4x\\6x\\8x\\10x\\12\\13") result is <PhoneNumber> (x\2x\4x\6x\8x\10x\12\13 </PhoneNumber>

Answer (score 1):

Hey check this function just give the phone number you want to mask as input to the function and it will return you the masked string

```js
function maskPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {

 var regularExpresion = /\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}/g, // regular expression to test phone numbers
  stringArray,
  maskString,
  lastString;
 
 // Check if given input matches the phone number pattern
 if(regularExpresion.test(phoneNumber)) {
  
  // split phone number to an array of characters to manipulate string
  stringArray = phoneNumber.split("");

  /* 
   * splice the array after reversing so that last 4 digits are seperated
   * Now stringArray will have last 4 digits and maskString will have remaining characters
   *
   */
  maskString = stringArray.reverse().splice(4);

  // reverse and join the array to get last 4 digits without any change
  lastString = stringArray.reverse().join("");

  // now replace the remaining characters where digits are present with "X" and then join the array
  // concat masked string with last 4 digits to get the required format
  phoneNumber = maskString.reverse().join("").replace(/\d/g,"X") + lastString;
 }

 return phoneNumber;
}
```